# efficiently searching through data using pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, search

i have 3 csv files, 1st has 1m records, 2nd has 2m, 3rd has 5m records.
file 1 has columns cust_id,fname,lname
file 2 has columns cust_id, prod_id, price, date
file 3 has columns prod_id, prod_code, price, quantity

so, what i want is select details of 10 customers from above three files and place them into 3 different new csv files. i.e. for each customer (from 10 customers) i want cust_id,fname,lname from file1 and place the result in new csv file, cust_id, prod_id, price, date from file2 place the result in new csv file, prod_id, prod_code, price, quantity from file3 place the result in new csv file.

code:

```
import pandas as pd

customers = pd.read_csv("customers10.csv")

customer_details = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")

products = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

product_items = pd.read_csv("file3.csv")

table1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=file1.columns)

table1 = pd.concat([customer_details[customer_details['cust_id'].isin(customer_details['cust_id'])],table1])

table2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=products.columns)

table2 = pd.concat([products[products['cust_id'].isin(customer_details['cust_id')],table2])

table3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=product_items.columns)

table3 = pd.concat([product_items[product_items['prod_id'].isin(products['prod_id'])],table3])
```

i want to operate this on files with millions of records, is this efficient to do or there are any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

pandas `read_csv()` has parameters that may be useful for relative large data sets, like these.  See `iterator`, `chunk size` and `memory_map` in the docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

pandas is an in-memory system, so 'large data set' is relative to the amount of RAM in the computer.